# @Autowired results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, dependency-injection

I have a Facelets/ JSF Managed Beans/ Hibernate application. Right now I am trying to implement DI into my beans via annotations. I have 2 of them: LoginBean, RegistrationBean (each responsible for the appropriate page). The problem is that whenever I try to autowire the property inside the RegistrationBean, i end up with NPE. But if I place the same class fields into LoginBean - they are autowired with no problem! Below are my ManagedBeans, applicationContext.xml (db settings are ok, so I won't post db.properties) and a class, which I am trying to autowire, Stacktrace.

With best regards.

Nazar

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dataart.mediaportal"/>

    <!-- DATA SOURCE AND PERSISTENCE SETTINGS-->
    <bean id="propertiesPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:db.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dmDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.dataart.mediaportal"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${db.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">${db.import_files}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${db.hbm2ddl_auto}</prop>
                <prop key="connection.pool_size">${db.pool_size}</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">${db.current_session_context_class}</prop>
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${db.provider_class}</prop>-->
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${db.use_second_level_cache}</prop>-->
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${db.use_query_cache}</prop>-->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dmDataSource" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dmDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

LoginBean:

```
package com.dataart.mediaportal.controller.bean;

import com.dataart.mediaportal.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl;
import com.dataart.mediaportal.model.User;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")
public class LoginBean extends BaseBean {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginBean.class);
    private User user;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    @Autowired
    private UserDAOImpl userDAO;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String authorize() {
        logger.debug("Searching user in database...");
        user = userDAO.login(login, password);
        if (user != null) {
            logger.debug("User found.");
            getSession(false).setAttribute("user", user);
            return "login";
        }
        logger.warn("User has not been found. Login: " + login + ", Password: " + password);
        return null;
    }

    public void logout() throws IOException {
        logger.debug("Loging out.");
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        logger.debug("Invalidating session...");
        ec.invalidateSession();
        logger.debug("Done. Forwarding to home page.");
        ec.redirect("login.xhtml");
    }

}
```

RegistrationBean:

```
package com.dataart.mediaportal.controller.bean;

import com.dataart.mediaportal.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl;
import com.dataart.mediaportal.model.User;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "registration")
@Scope("request")
public class RegistrationBean extends BaseBean {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private UserDAOImpl userDAO;
    private String regLogin;
    private String regPassword;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    @Autowired(required = true)
    private User user;


    public String getRegLogin() {
        return regLogin;
    }

    public void setRegLogin(String regLogin) {
        this.regLogin = regLogin;
    }

    public String getRegPassword() {
        return regPassword;
    }

    public void setRegPassword(String regPassword) {
        this.regPassword = regPassword;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String register() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(regPassword.getBytes());
        String hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);
        user.setUserLogin(regLogin);
        user.setUserPassword(hash);
        user.setUserName(name);
        user.setUserLastname(surname);
        user.setRoleId(0);

        if (userDAO.insertUser(user)) {
            getSession(false).setAttribute("user", user);
            return "home";
        } else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                    addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Registration failed!"));
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

User:

```
package com.dataart.mediaportal.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")})
@Component
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "user_login")
    private String userLogin;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32)
    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String userPassword;

    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "user_lastname")
    private String userLastname;

    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private Integer roleId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Album> albumList;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public User(Integer userId, String userLogin, String userPassword) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userLogin = userLogin;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    public String getUserLogin() {
        return userLogin;
    }

    public void setUserLogin(String userLogin) {
        this.userLogin = userLogin;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserLastname() {
        return userLastname;
    }

    public void setUserLastname(String userLastname) {
        this.userLastname = userLastname;
    }

    public Integer getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(Integer roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public List<Album> getAlbumList() {
        return albumList;
    }

    public void setAlbumList(List<Album> albumList) {
        this.albumList = albumList;
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{registration.register()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{registration.register()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dataart.mediaportal.controller.bean.RegistrationBean.register(RegistrationBean.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: There are too many issues with your code. Try to find a more suitable tutorial on JSF/Spring interaction. You can find some examples on stack overflow if you search a bit. As to the question *why*, it is because `@Autowired` doesn't work with `@ManagedBean`, as you erroneously expected. As you can understand, neither of the two proposed answers does *answer* your question. Instead, either make beans managed by Spring, thus removing all JSF-related annotations, or inject it via `@ManagedProperty`, thus removing all Spring-related stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing 'required = false' for the attribute 'userDAO', from RegistrationBean.

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't help. Any other clues?

Comment: Did u try removing '@Scope("request")' from RegistrationBean, which might have been restricting the DI to inject the beans?

Comment: Yes, I tried that already. I just can't get it. Why DI works fine in one class and rejects to work in another..

Comment: Please check the below tutorial for better understanding of JSF and Spring integration. http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/

Answer (score 0):

All that must be done in order to fix this issue is replacing:

```
@Component
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")
```

with

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
```

for every ManagedBean you have with it's own scopes and props.

Answer (score -1):

The stack trace indicating the NPE at line 69 of your registration bean when you try to bind your jsf form inputs to your user bean. In login bean it works fine because you're not doing any data binding, you are calling the Dao and assigning the return value to a User object.

Your NPE results as a data binding issue related probably to your JSF form, but not to the AutoWire setting.

Also I would set the approriate getter and setter method for your user field inside RegistrationBean

Comment: It doesnt matter for @Autowire if you have getter/setter or no.